# In Ajax when we use modal popup if you click on OK button there should not be postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

Any code related to modal popup to stablise is necessary..........and if the values are enter correctly then modal popup should get post back.....................

Please have the code  in .Net

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this as well.  Assuming you are launching the dialogue via a button, and wiring up the button like this:

$("#buttonID")
    .click(function() {
    $("#dialog-vendorcontact").dialog("open");
}

On some browsers, clicking the button will launch the dialogue, but immediately submit the form.  The fix is easy, add "return false" to the button on click event:

<button id="buttonID" **onclick="return false;"**> Show my Diaglogue </button>

P

Comment: Please i need to know how do to stop the modelpopup when page postback